# How to print() an object in list in Python

Tags: python, oop

I stored my object in a list and then when i print it out, it show me this:

```
<__main__.Student object at 0x7f76d80d8198>
```

Here is my code:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, std_id, std_name, std_dob, std_mark=0):
        self.student_id = std_id
        self.student_name = std_name
        self.student_dob = std_dob
        self.student_mark = std_mark

    def input(self, std_id, std_name, std_dob, std_mark):
        student = Student(std_id, std_name, std_dob,std_mark)
        Students.append(student)
```

As you can see, "Students" is my list, and my list is append the object "student". However, i can use this function

```
def list_student(self, student):
        print("ID: ", student.student_id)
        print("Name: ", student.student_name)
        print("Dob: ", student.student_dob)
        print("GPA: ",student.student_mark)
        print("\n")
```

to observe my object, but i want to see it in my list with "print(Students)". Can anyone suggest how to do it? Thanks alot!

Comment: You have to implement `__repr__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your `list_student` function into a `__repr__` method on `Student`:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, std_id, std_name, std_dob, std_mark=0):
        self.student_id = std_id
        self.student_name = std_name
        self.student_dob = std_dob
        self.student_mark = std_mark

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f"ID: {self.student_id}\n"
            f"Name: {self.student_name}\n"
            f"Dob: {self.student_dob}\n"
            f"GPA: {self.student_mark}\n"
        )
```

Now any time you `print` a `Student` (even in a list), you'll get a string with that formatting instead of the default `<__main__.Student object at xxxxx>` one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__str__` function inside the class (Your code needed a few modification, and maybe, still does):

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, std_id, std_name, std_dob, std_mark=0):
        self.student_id = std_id
        self.student_name = std_name
        self.student_dob = std_dob
        self.student_mark = std_mark

    def input(self, std_id, std_name, std_dob, std_mark):
        student = Student(std_id, std_name, std_dob,std_mark)
        Students.append(student)

    def __str__(self):
        toShow = ""
        toShow += "ID: "+ str(self.student_id) + "\n"
        toShow += "Name: "+ str(self.student_name) + "\n"
        toShow += "Dob: "+ str(self.student_dob) + "\n"
        toShow += "GPA: "+ str(self.student_mark) + "\n"
        toShow += "\n"
        return toShow
```

##### Example

```
exmStudent = Student(1234, "Amir", "Std_dob", -20)
print(exmStudent)
```

##### Output

```
ID: 1234
Name: Amir
Dob: Std_dob
GPA: -20
```

Comment: this won't work for `print([exmStudent])` though

Comment: notice, I put it in a list, `[exmStudent]`. the `list.__str__` uses the `__repr__` of the objects it contains

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, you are absolutely right. But, Honestly, I am not sure that makes a difference. Of course what Sam provided is way better, but `__str__` does almost what OP asked for.